# How to append an uploaded file name?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem appending the imageNameArray where it is suppose to display file names which have been uploaded.

The problem is that lets say I previously uploaded 3 files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png), when I refresh page and upload another file (panda.png), then when I upload the file, it should display 'panda.png'. But instead it is just appending the name of the previously uploaded file (pig.png) and it does not append panda.png.

IT DISPLAYS:

```
pig.png
```

IT SHOULD BE:

```
panda.png
```

If I upload another file (not refreshing page) such as monkey.png, then again it appends pig.png. No monkey.png.

IT DISPLAYS:

```
pig.png
pig.png
```

IT SHOULD BE:

```
 panda.png
 monkey.png
```

How can the code below be fixed so that it appends the file names as it should do above?

Below is the javascript code where the appending occurs:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $idx = count($_POST ['fileImage']) -1 ;
    $output = isset($_POST ['fileImage'][$idx]) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'][$idx]['name'] : "";

    ?>

              function stopImageUpload(success){

              var imageNameArray = ['<?php echo $output ?>'];
              var result = '';



              if (success == 1){
                 result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';

                    for(var i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)
            {
                 $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');

             }

              }
              else {
                 result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
              }

        return true;

        }
```

Below is the php script where it uploads a file which is on another page from the javascript function above:

```
        <?php

            session_start();

            $result = 0;
            $errors = array ();
            $dirImage = "ImageFiles/";


        if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

        $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );


        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

                if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
                    if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                        $result = 1;


                    }
                }

            }

    $_POST ['fileImage'][] = array('name' => $_FILES ['fileImage']['name']);

            ?>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you useing Session?
try to add session_destroy(); in the end of the second script and the first one.
I think its should delete all the previos data and then you know more whats the problem.

Comment: If I don't use $_SESSION then I won't be able to retrieve the file's name from the php script.

Comment: I will test $_POST, give me 5 mins :)

Comment: I have updated code so that it includes $_POST. If I use $_POST then it gives me an undefined index 'fileImage' on this line: $idx = count($_POST ['fileImage']) -1 ; Why is it giving me this undefined index because 'fileImage' is the correct index.